# Is it possible to run a App Web as part of Google Apps Script Add On?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm developing my first Google Apps Script (GAS) Add-On. Specifically I'm trying to redeploy an existing [container-bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) (specifically sheets-bound) script I've written, with a Web-App, as an Add-On.

That original script implements a `doGet(e)` and `doPost(e)` as per GAS's `HTML Service` [framework](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/). It has been deployed via the Script Editor's  **Publish > Deploy as web app** [dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app):

[image: Deploy as web app]

The purpose of the Web App is to expose a UX for a given Sheet when this Add-On is enabled.  If possible, how do you get a Sheet's Web-App endpoint programmatically? That is the `Current web app URL` in the following dialog:

[image: Current web app URL]

The goal is to only publish the Add-On privately for a given domain. My fallback is to manually install (e.g. copy & paste) the existing script in every Sheet I need it in.

Answer (score 1):

The getUrl() method of Service Class will return the web app URL.

```
ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit. Just figured out this is the way to get the endpoint if you're deploying a standalone or container-bound web-app. But this doesn't doesn't answer the main question ... going to try and rephrase it

Comment: I also don't understand the question then. It looks like @Amit Agarwal answered you the way you have phrased the question currently.